# Why doesn't FMX.Canvas.Mac ever call CFRelease after calling CFNumberCreate?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

According to [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542182-cfnumbercreate), CFNumberCreate follows The Create Rule. However, whereas numerous CF..Create calls in FMX.Canvas.Mac are followed by CFRelease calls on the returned objects, CFNumberCreate calls are not. Why is this?

Comment: After some more research and testing, it seems abundantly clear that this is just bad code in Firemonkey, leaking references to numbers like crazy.

Comment: [File a bug report with Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in FMX.Canvas.Mac. A call to CFNumberCreate needs to be balanced with a call to CFRelease.

Bug report: [RSP-20924](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20924)